# Linear-gradient on IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, html-table, linear-gradients

I'm trying to do a Linear Gradient transparent on Table Rows and I did it but only for `Chrome`. I needed to have to work on `IE`

I send [the code](https://jsfiddle.net/hL75rxn4/) I have to help understand my problem.

[image]

Comment: Personally, I wouldn’t even bother to support IE anymore. However you can use an actual image of the gradient as background-image as a fallback.

Comment: But actually I need to do it for IE and not for Chrome. However I tried using Background-image but it changes the table background and not the Rows text.

Comment: The issue is related to the [mask-image CSS property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mask-image), it doesn't support IE browser, so the mask layer hasn't displayed in IE browser. As you said, if we we add a mask layer for the Rows, it just change the background image not the rows text, I think you could try to use the [css opacity property](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_opacity.asp) sets the opacity level for an element, like [this sample](http://jsfiddle.net/vp3bz1qh/), you could refer to it.